# Reading expected results from a sql table

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have been looking into that from any source I know.. I still don't get it.. Even though, I understand how that works, but I must be doing something wrong.

I am using Pyunit to create a test where I read data from a table and then I need to compare results.

For example :

```
create table test_table (a int, b char(30)
insert into test_table values (1, "good day today")
insert into test_table values (2, "bad day today")
insert into test_table values (3,"snow day today")

select * from test_table
```

Now in the python code side :

```
cursor.execute("select * from test_table")
expected = "(1,'good day today'), (2, 'bad day today'), (3,'show day today')"
res=fetch.all(cursor)

assert.equal(res,expected)
```

So this is just an example of my code from work, but basically this is where I am stuck.

How can I test verified my expected results from the SQL table?

Comment: Your approach appears sane with the exception that `res` is typically a sequence of tuples, and `expected` should be as well (i.e. not a string).

Comment: Ok can you give me examples ?

Comment: List of tuples example: `expected = [(1,'good day today'), (2, 'bad day today'), (3,'show day today')]`

Comment: I see thank you.    So the fech.all() method always going to use this format (sequence of tuples).   I am asking you that, because I have many test cases where I have to test the expected results.

Comment: Yes, `.fetch_all()` returns a sequence of tuples provided the module you use to connect to the DB conforms to [the DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).